# Java - cover all JButtton size with ImageIcon

Tags: java, imageicon

How do I cover all my JButton with the ImageIcon given?

my JButtoon size is 90x90 and my Image as well

I also set a text to my JButton (the text is necessary for the program to work)

**Code:** (I get a padding inside mi button)

```
btnBoton[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j));
btnBoton[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("img//"+num+".jpg"));
```

[image]

(When I comment my setText):

```
//btnBoton[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j));
btnBoton[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("img//"+num+".jpg"));
```

[image]

I'm trying to acomplish as the second image but without commenting my setText

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two methods to place text at the center of buttons

```
btnBoton[i][j].setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
btnBoton[i][j].setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
```

and texts will be placed in center of buttons,

if you want to assign a value to buttons and don't showing any text, instead of `.setText()`,create a new class like `MJButton` which extends `JButton` and create a String field to it named `tag` or `data` or etc. then encapsulate the field and use `.setTag()` and `.getTag()` to do so.

```
class MJButton extends JButton {

    private String tag;

    public MJButton(String tag, Icon icon) {
        super( icon);
        this.tag = tag;
    }


    public MJButton() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

}
```

so use this new class to create buttons, in two ways:

- 1: `btnBoton[i][j] = new MJButton();`
  and call `.setTag()` for them:

  ```
  btnBoton[i][j].setTag(Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j));
  ```
- 2: assign icon and tag to button in one line using second constructor

  ```
  btnBoton[i][j] = new MJButton((Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j)), new ImageIcon("img//"+num+".jpg"));
  ```